# How to get the Jacobian matrix form derivative of vector by vector in TensorFlow Eager Execution API?

Tags: tensorflow, autodiff

In the MLP model the input of layer l can be computed by this formula:
z = Wa + b
W is the weight matrix between layer `l-1` and layer `l`, a is the output signal of layer `l-1` neuron, b is the bias of layer `l`.
For example:

[image]

I want to use TensorFlow Eager Execution API to get the derivatives:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I define a function to calculate the value of z:

```
def f002(W, a, b):
    return tf.matmul(W, a) + b
```

My main program:

```
def test001(args={}):
    tf.enable_eager_execution()
    tfe = tf.contrib.eager

    a = tf.reshape(tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), [3, 1])
    W = tf.constant([[4.0, 5.0, 6.0],[7.0, 8.0, 9.0]])
    b = tf.reshape(tf.constant([1001.0, 1002.0]), [2, 1])
    z = f002(W, a, b)
    print(z)
    grad_f1 = tfe.gradients_function(f002)
    dv = grad_f1(W, a, b)
    print(dv)
```

I can get the correct value of z in forward mode. But when print the derivative results it displayed something like these:

```
[<tf.Tensor: id=17, shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: id=18, shape=(3, 1), 
dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[11.],
       [13.],
       [15.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: id=16, shape=(2, 1), 
dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)>]
```

This is not what I want. How to get the Jacobian matrix derivative result of vector by vector?

Comment: I know that I can use the custom derivative feature in TensorFlow Eager Execution API. I should calculate the correct derivatives by myself. But I believe that TensorFlow Eager Execution API provide this function. I want to know how to do.